# How to read images from mobile library

Tags: flutter

I am looking for flutter package that can help in reading images in mobile library. Any idea if such a package exists

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A Flutter plugin for iOS and Android for picking images from the image library, and taking new pictures with the camera.

```
$ flutter pub add image_picker
```

Comment: I am not interested in picking an image, i am interested in reading the list of images in the mobile library..  image_picker is not thee solution to everything

Comment: I guess you are expecting a package like photo_view

Comment: I am already using photo_view but I need the list of images in the mobile library so that I can show them in the photo_view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar.  The photo_gallery package may be appropriate:  https://pub.dev/packages/photo_gallery